# How to set "Accept" and "Content-Type" header in Restlet 2.3.4

Tags: restlet

I want to set `"Content-Type"="application/json"` and `"Accept"="application/json"` in **Restlet 2.3.4**?

before 2.3.4 I used the following code and it worked:

```
Series<Header> requestHeaders=(Series<Header>)cr.getRequestAttributes().get(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);
if(requestHeaders==null){
   requestHeaders=new Series(Header.class);
   cr.getRequestAttributes().put(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, requestHeaders);
}
requestHeaders.add(new Header(key,value));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Content-Type` should be set as part of the `Representation` object that you are sending to the server, (Other representations are available).

```
new StringRepresentation("{}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

While the Accepts header should ideally be set using the `ClientResource#accept(Metadata)` [JavaDoc](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jse/api/org/restlet/resource/ClientResource.html#accept(org.restlet.data.Metadata...)%20accept(Metadata)) Which I am assuming is your what your instance object `cr` is, please be explicit about this.  This method is a shortcut into the `ClientInformation` object.

Given that `MediaType` extends `Metadata` this becomes.

```
cr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the Restlet API instead of defining by hand headers. Restlet does the job for you. Within very last versions of the tool, doing this isn't allowed anymore.

Regarding the content type, there are two approaches:

- Explicit one by working with representations themselves and setting the media types.
- Implicit one by leveraging annotated interface and the conversion feature of Restlet. This allows to work on beans for representations instead of raw representations (class `Representation` and its sub classes). In this case, the converterService selects the right metdia type for your needs.

Regarding the content negotiation (CONNEG, i.e. header `Accept`), we can specify it directly within the method you use:

```
// Raw representation
ClientResource cr = (...)
Representation repr = cr.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

// Beans
ClientResource cr = (...)
cr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
MyAnnotatedInterface resource = cr.wrap(MyAnnotatedInterface.class);
MyBean bean = resource.getBean();

// MyAnnotatedInterface
public class MyAnnotatedInterface {
    @Get
    MyBean getBean();
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry